# Remove Filtered Signal Lag

Tags: .net, vb.net, signal-processing, median, digital-filter

I have used MathDotNet library and implemented digital filtration on the input signal. I am getting 40 samples from my ADC and I am filtering each data sample as I get them. I have used FIR online filter and 2 median filter. [image] In the image there is a red line which is the raw signal and a blue line which is filtered signal. As seen there is a phase shift in my filtered signal. I want to remove it. Any ideas how to do it?

If you want to see my code in vb.net for some idea, then I can post it too.

Comment: Depending on how your code works (time base wise), you might have simple problems like when to draw both curves relative to each other. But also, if I remember my signal processing classes from 25 years ago correctly... you cannot create 0 phase filters with FIR filters... (don't slay me if I am wrong on that!). http://dspguru.com/dsp/faqs/fir/properties

Comment: So you are saying that the phase lag that i am getting is acceptable ? If you have some idea on vb.net programming i can post the code for some idea. For now i stay with that phase lag.

Comment: The link I gave in my previous comment would allow you to estimate your systematic FIR filter lag from the order of your FIR filter (40 I think) alone. If that is consistent with what your graph shows, you have your explanation. If not, you would have to examine how the drawing and the time management of your graph works.

Comment: As @SluethEye mentioned, this delay is expected and is directly related to the sampling frequency and the filter order. Generally an IIR filter can realize the same frequency response at much lower order and hence lower phase delay. That said, you have to be careful about the instability and non-linear phase response aspects of IIR filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a linear phase FIR filter with `N` coefficients operating on a signal sampled at a sampling frequency `fs`, the filter will introduce a delay of `0.5*(N-1)*fs` (see for example [dspGuru.com](http://dspguru.com/dsp/faqs/fir/properties)). This is perfectly normal.

To ease the comparison with the unfiltered signal, you may consider either:

1. Delaying the unfiltered signal by the same amount; or
2. Shifting back the filtered signal by the delay amount on the graph